# Subgroups and basis of finite Abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

There is a result about the free Abelian group that says:

> Let $F$ be a free abelian group of rank $n$ and let $H$ be a subgroup
> of $F.$  There exists a basis $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ of $F$ and integers $d_1,...,d_r > 0 $ such
> that $\{d_1x_1,\ldots,d_rx_r\}$ is a basis of $H$.

I wondered if we could say something similar for the finite abelian group.

**Question:** Given a finite abelian group $G$, and a subgroup $H$ of $G$, does there exist a basis  $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ of $G$ and integers $d_1,...,d_r > 0 $ such that $\{d_1x_1,\ldots,d_rx_r\}$ is a basis of $H$?

We know a finite Abelian group $G$ can be represented as a direct product of cyclic groups. However, not all subgroups of $G$ are direct products of subgroups of these cyclic groups. So in general we can't use the basis that consists of the generators of these cyclic groups.

Comment: Not always. This has certainly been asked before. $C_8 \oplus C_2$ has a subgroup of order 4 that is not of this form.

Comment: Thank you @DerekHolt